# Having trouble overriding storage directory using Carrierwave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I watched Railscast 253 and decided to use Carrierwave for my file uploading needs. I know I must be doing something very dumb, but I am neither successful in overriding the store_dir method nor the filename method in my uploader. The following is my code which nearly identical to Ryan Bates' code in the Railscast.

```
class DocumentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # some stuff here

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "documents/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # more stuff here

  def filename
    "#{active_customer.last_name}_#{active_customer.first_name}_#{active_system.desc}.pdf" if original_filename
  end


end
```

The uploaded files are instead being stored in `public/uploads/tmp` with some default file name. What could I be doing wrong here? Is there an important step in the Carrierwave set up that maybe Ryan Bates did not include in the Railscast?

Comment: Can you check to ensure that the directory exists?

Comment: Ya it's there in the public folder. I put it there myself. Is that name allowed? documents?

Comment: Try prefixing that path with public like this `"public/documents/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
`